# md5 is a good function for finding duplicate files?

Tags: hashmap, md5, hashset

I needed to check if a picture is included in a big set of pictures already (more than 2 million pictures). So, I implemented a persistent hash list using md5 as hash function. Later, i have read md5 has some issues and that better functions have been developed. Do you think there is a better function for my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use MD5 for anything where security is important. MD5 [is](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/) [broken](http://packetstormsecurity.org/files/41548/md5coll.c.html).

For simple duplicate detection you should be fine. (there is no attacker in your scenario)

If there is a possibility that your code will ever be used in a setting where security is needed use a secure alternative. **[SHA-265](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)** is a good candidate. [Git uses](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) but you should [not use it for new applications](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/shs/hash_standards_comments.pdf)

A fast non-cryptographic hash-function is [MurmurHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash). Use this if you need maximum performance.